# BRIN Index on PostGIS Geography

Tags: postgis, spatial-index, geography-data-type

I have about 1.5 billion points in a geography column which represent topography.

I'll be retrieving all the points that are within a certain distance of a given long/lat. I was able to create a GIST index and query the table using ST_DWithin. These queries run in 40-50 ms.

The data in question is static. I believe a BRIN index would be quite a bit smaller and possibly faster but I've been having trouble getting it to run in anywhere near as as fast as the GIST index. I've let it run for about 5 minutes before canceling the query.

Here's how the table and index are setup. I got this method from the PostGIS docs:

```
CREATE TABLE topo
(
    location geography(Point,4326) NOT NULL,
    elevation smallint NOT NULL
)

#Create a temp index
CREATE INDEX idx_temp_topo ON topo2 USING btree(ST_GeoHash(location::geometry,4326));

#Order rows based on temp index
CLUSTER topo2 USING idx_temp_topo;

#Create BRIN index
CREATE INDEX topo_location_ix ON topo USING BRIN( location );

#Drop temp index
DROP INDEX idx_temp_topo;

#Vacuum
VACUUM ANALYZE topo2;
```

Query Plan

```
SELECT * FROM topo WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_MakePoint(-124.99875, 30.001250199900003), 100);


    #   Node
1.  Gather
2.  Bitmap Heap Scan on topo as topo
Filter: st_dwithin(location, '0101000020E610000052B81E85EB3F5FC019AFDFEE51003E40'::geography, '100'::double precision, true)
3.  Bitmap Index Scan using topo_location_ix
Index Cond: (location && _st_expand('0101000020E610000052B81E85EB3F5FC019AFDFEE51003E40'::geography, '100'::double precision))
```

Comment: what is your question? - you seem to have answered your query as to which index is faster.

Comment: Try reducing BRIN block size; the default is 128 blocks, and a block corresponds to one page of a relation. `<SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>;> / <SELECT relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname = '<table>’;> * 128` will get you the actual amount of `location` geometries that are fetched **per index hit** (of which there *may* be plenty), and that have to be **calculated** with `ST_DWithin` (which, too give a comparison, is like running `ST_Distance <= <threshold>` between all those `location`s per index hit, and the reference point)

Comment: Even assuming the *thousand million* definition, 1.5 billion is an awful lot of features. Because it is static, you might consider chunking your points into multipoints with a 200-1000 meter extents, which will significantly reduce the row count, and serve to defragment the points. Performance will depend on how fast the multipoint can be unpacked.

Comment: just to rule that out: there is a mix between tables `topo` and `topo2` in your code, so make sure the proper indexing/analyzing etc is done on the table that will be queried

Comment: @IanTurton I'm assuming that I'm not indexing the data properly. From what I've read a BRIN will be faster when the index doesn't fit into memory a bit slower when it does. With a GIST index I get results in ~40ms.  With a BRIN I'm waiting several minutes and eventually canceling the query.

Comment: I've tried reducing the block size but it didn't seem to help (at least not enough for the query to return in less then 5 minutes). I could chunk the points but it seems like I'm missing something with the BRIN index considering the performance difference. I created a topo2 table which consists of 1M rows from topo. With no index or a BRIN the query takes ~750 ms. With a GIST it takes ~12ms. It seems off that the BRIN index doesn't improve performance at all. Makes me think I'm missing something. The mixup between topo and topo2 was in copying queries to SE. They're correct in the DB.

Comment: Try doing a test using the geometry type instead. Your results looks like the index is providing no selectivity at all, maybe the implementation on geography is very wrong.